# huffman code - cant decompress BMP files using bitset

Tags: java, bitmap, huffman-code, bitset

I built a classic Hoffman code, with encoder and decoder. I noticed that I had a problem, I use code in "bitset", to compress the input file. But the "bitset" - does not decode all the files I send to, for example when I send a txt file, it works great, but when I send other files like BMP. It doesn't work.
Before I used bitset - the code worked - but without any compression - so I'm afraid the problem is with bitset.

The decoder I built is:

```
    public void Decompress(String[] input_names, String[] output_names) {

        HuffmanVerticle tree = new HuffmanVerticle();
        tree = readTreeFile(output_names);
        restoreInput(tree, output_names, input_names);

    }

    public static void restoreInput(HuffmanVerticle tree, String[] binary_names, String[] original_names) {
        BitSet huffmanCodeBit;
        try {
            FileOutputStream to_original = new FileOutputStream(original_names[0]); 
            FileInputStream binary = new FileInputStream(binary_names[0]);
            ObjectInputStream s = new ObjectInputStream(binary);
            huffmanCodeBit = (BitSet) s.readObject();
            System.out.println(huffmanCodeBit.toString());

            int index = 0;
            while(huffmanCodeBit.length() > index)
            {   
                HuffmanVerticle tmp = tree;
                while (!tmp.isNullTree()) 
                {
                    boolean bit = huffmanCodeBit.get(index);
                    index++;
                    System.out.println(bit);
                    if (!bit) 
                        tmp = tmp.left;
                    else
                        tmp = tmp.right;
                }
                to_original.write(tmp.character);
            }

            binary.close();
            to_original.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

What am I missing here? Why doesn't the code work for certain files? I'm trying to run the code on some files but it doesn't work, the files that come back don't work.
The code does not work for bmp files at all, even after half an hour, for example txt files, it runs very fast.
Thank for your help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It would be difficult to answer your question without the code for `HuffmanVerticle`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I arranged the question, is it okay?
Can you tell me where the issue is unclear?

Comment: From your description it sounds like your code goes into an infinite loop. There are several way how this could happen, but it is impossible to know without seeing your code. `HuffmanVerticle` is not part of the standard library, it's a class you wrote, right? It would be important to know what this class looks like and what `readTreeFile` does to tell what the problem is. For example, if the tree returned by `readTreeFile` already satisfies `isNullTree`, your code would go into an infinite loop because it cannot increment `index` often enough to get out of the loop.

Comment: Also, do you want `BitSet` to just hold the raw bits from the input file? If so, `readObject` would be the wrong way to go, it is meant for object serialization. It only makes sense if you previously wrote the `BitSet` to the file with `writeObject`. If you want it to have the raw bits from the file, you would have to use something `BitSet#valueOf`.